# Get the number/id of the group that made the match in regex

Tags: java, regex

I just wrote code for 2 hours thinking that `Matcher.group()` returned the number/id of the group that made the match in regex. Simplified example of what I did:

```
//    Group   -1-   -2- 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(abc)|(def)");
String t = "abc abc def def abc";

for (Matcher m = p.matcher(t); m.find(); ) {
    System.out.print( m.group() );
}
```

I thought that this would output `1, 1, 2, 2, 1`, the number of the group for each match. Instead, it actually returns the part that a group matched. Is there any other method or any way to achieve the result I want?

Comment: Pattern `Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Pattern`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `group` result(s) to see which one was matched:

```
for (Matcher m = p.matcher(t); m.find(); ) {
    if (m.group(1) != null) {
        System.out.print("1, ");
    } else {
        System.out.print("2, ");
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you have a lot of groups and don't want to hardcode them, you can loop over them instead (assuming they're still exclusive):

```
for (Matcher m = p.matcher(t); m.find(); ) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
        if (m.group(i) != null) {
            System.out.print(i + ", ");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about it, but you see, my regex is enormous (>1000 characters) so is my text, and time is an issue. Will it affect performance much?

Comment: Twenty-one groups